# I got stuck converting a especific dictionary to a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, deployment, ibm-watson

I have a dictionary and I got stuck while trying to convert to a pandas dataframe.

It's a result of scoring an IBM ML model. The result comes in this format and I would like to transform this dictionary to a pandas dataframe in order to merge later with the original dataframe that was scored.

Dictionary:

```
{'predictions': [{'fields': ['prediction', 'probability'], 'values': [['Creditworthy', [0.5522992460276774, 0.4477007539723226]]]}]}
```

[image of the code which generated this dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBeV1.png)

I would like a pandas dataframe like this:

```
  index  predictions  prediction  probability
      0 Creditworthy    0.552299     0.447701
```

Comment: I think it's hard for even human being to convert it as df. Could you  give some logical explanation to this?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah, for sure! It's a result of scoring a ML model. The result comes in this format and I would like to transform this dictionary to a pandas dataframe in order to merge later with the original dataframe that was scored.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah I've just added an image of the code on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the source dictionary is in value named *dct*.

Start from reading column names:

```
cols = dct['predictions'][0]['fields']
```

Then create DataFrame in a form which can be read from this dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dct['predictions'][0]['values'],
    columns=['predictions', 'val'])
```

For the time being, values are in *val* column, as a list:

```
    predictions                                       val
0  Creditworthy  [0.5522992460276774, 0.4477007539723226]
```

Then break *val* column into separate columns, setting at the same time
proper column names (read before):

```
df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(df.val.values.tolist())
```

And the only thing to do is to drop *val* columns:

```
df.drop(columns=['val'], inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
    predictions  prediction  probability
0  Creditworthy    0.552299     0.447701
```

Just as it should be.

Comment: For sure! Thank you again!